# how to construct graph api for one facebook fanpage feed?

Tags: android, facebook

Below is to get the all the fan page feed.
graph.facebook.com/100005400245816?fields=feed

How do i make the graph api for one facebook fanpage feed with comments and likes?

Answer (score 0):

When you list all feeds from fanpage pick **id** from that data to get details.
Use that post **id** to get all details with 3 comments and likes.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[id]?access_token=[access_token]
```

To get all the comments you need to use the link below

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[id]/comments?access_token=[access_token]
```

You can use same link for likes also just replace **comments** with **likes**